# need to validate user age is greater than 18 using #joi validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, joi

```
const  Joi = require('joi')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    firstName: {
        type: String,
        allowNull : false
    },
    middleName: {
        type: String,
        allowNull : false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        allowNull : false
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        allowNull : false
    },

    dob: Joi.date().max('1-1-2004').iso(),

    address : {
        type : String,
        allowNull : false
    },
    passportImage : {
        type : String,
    },
    status : {
        type : String,
        enum : ['pending by approval-1','pending by approval-2','Rejected','Accepted'],
        default : 'pending by approval-1'
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: That's great that you need to do that. Did you have a question, because this is a question that you created. You need to either show us some sort of attempt at trying to write the code, and share with us any debugging &/or troubleshooting details you have, or explain to us what you don't understand, and why you were unable to start writing the program, that you stated you want to write.

Comment: I wanted to add the date of birth and that date of birth will get validate by JOI validator and if the age will be the less than 18 then it should give an error else data should be saved in the database

Comment: Did you try to add it, is there something you don't know how to do, that you need to know so you are able to add it? Is there somthing preventing you from writing the code that adds it? Is there some reason why you can't add it (different than unable to add it)? Does an error occur when you add it, and you don't know how to fix the error? There must be some reason why you haven't wrote the code yourself yet, unless what you want is for someone to write code for you, which if that's the case, most of us are paid programmers, and will write code for the write amount.

Comment: What I am saying, is: _"I won't just write code for you, but I will help you to understand something, or help you if your stuck."_ But you need to explain what you have tried, and what the problem &/or issue is. What it is that you don't know how to do, or don't know how to solve.

Comment: dob: Joi.date().max('1-1-2004').iso(), here when I hit the API at that time I have to check  as per the DOB that age is greater than 18 or not I use this method but it isn't working